# JS How to find target that is causing bubbling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

First off, Are there any good resources, or can someone tell me what is the best way to find what element is causing bubbling?

The bubbling is being caused by `touchmove` on mobile device.

So what I was planning to do is

```
$('.target-thats-bubbling').bind("touchmove", function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();       
   });
```

So second, would that code above work? if what I say is true about the `touchmove`causing the bubbling

If I am wrong about `touchmove` causing bubbling, let me know. I haven't found anything that says it can't cause bubbling.

Thanks

Comment: `var bubbled_event = event.target == event.currentTarget ? event : false;`

Answer (score 1):

Usually `event.target` contains a link to the element which cause bubbling.

Yes, `touchmove` event cause bubbling.

[Useful resource on touch events](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml).